# 16.04 to 18.04 distro upgrade stopped at 'remove old files' question

Tags: upgrade

I was trying to upgrade from 16.04.5 to 18.04 for the last several hours through console. Then I came across a question about deleting old files taking several hours with the options: yes no or details. I selected details to check out what was going to be deleted. got down to the end and there was no way to get back to the question. I tried several things but nothing worked. Now I can't even shutdown or restart normally and I afraid to do a power reboot. any ideas?

Comment: Please post some screen shots with actual error messages.

Comment: Hit q or ctrl-c

Comment: The Konsole has ended I cannot continue the update. But still not able to shutdown normally. Incomplete upgrade is going to crash my system isn't it? Is there a command to continue the update?